# What are different ways to create new connection using SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed `SQL developer` few months back to test queries `locally` . 
Is it necessary to install `oracle server 10g/11g` to create new connection ?
 Currently i am using `virtual box and Oracle_DB_Developer_VM_new.ova` to create a new connection . It makes system slow when i ran virtual box . There is any way to connect to other server like mysql DB sever or Tomcat sever e.t.c. .
**Note : Server is running locally for testing purpose .**

Comment: "*connect to Tomcat server*" makes absolutely no sense. SQL Developer is a SQL client that needs to talk to a (supported) DBMS. Tomcat is not a DBMS. And yes, you can connect to MySQL, see the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25259_01/appdev.31/e24285/intro.htm#CHDHIFGJ

Comment: You seem to be confused between web/app server and DB server. No doubt why your topuc title is so absurd compared to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html). It runs much leaner than a full database install, which is what you have with your Developer Day VirtualBox VM.

And yes, you can connect to MySQL - assuming you have the MySQL JDBC Jars and an actual MySQL Database to play with.